# Setting an id on an element created from a template element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a template element that I use to create `<li>`-Elements on my page. I can set the textContent attributes of the inner elements of that template. However I can not set the id for the parent element inside the template.

```
<template id="list-item">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media-body">
      <strong class="list-item-text"></strong>
      <p class="list-item-text"></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>

<div id="output"></div>
```

And this is the required js to demonstrate the issue.

```
var template = document.querySelector('#list-item');
var listItem = document.importNode(template.content, true);
var lines = listItem.querySelectorAll('.list-item-text');

lines[0].textContent = 'title';
lines[1].textContent = 'description';
listItem.id = 5;

document.querySelector('#output').appendChild(listItem);
```

Text contents will be set correctly, however the id won't be set at all (the js attribute gets created but it does not appear in the DOM.

I also created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53t88z78/) for this.

How can I set the id of the newly appended element? My current approach is to avoid templates in general and use strings in order to construct the element, which makes me feel dirty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to handle a `document-fragment` (listItem) as an `DOM element`. Instead, you should first get/query the element from the document-fragment as follows:

```
var docFragment = document.importNode(template.content, true);
var listItem = docFragment.querySelector('li');
```

See **[working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53t88z78/1/)**

Also, see documentation about `DocumentFragment` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `listItem.querySelector()` on the `document-fragment` and change the id then:

```
listItem.querySelector("li").id = 5;
```

---

```
var template = document.querySelector('#list-item');
var listItem = document.importNode(template.content, true);
var lines = listItem.querySelectorAll('.list-item-text');

lines[0].textContent = 'title';
lines[1].textContent = 'description';
listItem.querySelector("li").id = 5;
document.querySelector('#output').appendChild(listItem);
```